# While compiling COM server with Matlab Builder NE, I keep on getting the error : "Description: MCR instance is not available"

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I am trying to compile a COM object in Matlab 2011a using Matlab Builder NE.
I managed to build and package it, deploy it, and even to start the COM server.
I am using the following command in Matlab

> c = actxserver('MyFirstComServer.Class1');

However, when I try to run any method on this handle, I get an error message like that:

> c.GetNames(0,'')
>   ??? Invoke Error, Dispatch Exception:
>   Source: MyFirstComServer.Class1.1_0
>   Description: MCR instance is not available

I have found something on the web related to it, however, it did not help me
http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-2VS4TC/index.html?product=MN&solution=1-2VS4TC

Does anybody have any idea what to do?

Edit:
I've found out that the problem happens **only** if I call the component from Matlab.. This might have to do something with MCR confusion, the COM component uses the same MCR that Matlab uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that the problem happens only if I call the component from Matlab.. This might have to do something with MCR confusion, the COM component uses the same MCR that Matlab uses.

**Edit(1)** From Builder NE manual.

> Testing with the MCR
>   When you test with the MCR, keep in mind that the MCR is an instance of
>   MATLAB. Given this, it is not possible to load the MCR into MATLAB.
>   For example, if you build a generic COM component with the Deployment
>   Tool from MATLAB Builder NE, you generate a DLL.
>   If you then try to test the component with an application such as actxserver,
>   which loads its process into MATLAB, you are effectively loading the MCR
>   into MATLAB, producing an error such as this:
>   mwsamp.mymagic(3,[],[])
>   ??? Invoke Error, Dispatch Exception:
>   Source: tmw1.Class1.1_0
>   Description: MCR instance is not available
>   Therefore, understand the behaviors of third-party processes before
>   attempting to test them with the MCR.
>   If you are uncertain about the behavior of these processes, contact your
>   developer or systems administrator.